# Finding what happened between two PDFs from the parameters of a resulting PDF

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, density-function, distributions

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian random variables with PDFs of $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ with parameters of $(\mu_x, \Sigma_x)$ and $(\mu_y, \Sigma_y)$, we know that:

- for the operation of sum ($+$), if $h(Z) = f(X) + g(Y)$, then $h(Z)$ is PDF with parameters of ($\mu_z$, $\Sigma_z$) where $\mu_z = \mu_x +\mu_y$ and $\Sigma_z=\Sigma_x + \Sigma_y$
- for the operation of convolution ($*$), if $h(Z) = f(X) * g(Y)$, then $h(Z)$ is PDF with parameters of $(\mu_z, \Sigma_z)$ where $\mu_z = \mu_x +\mu_y$ and $\Sigma_z=\Sigma_x + \Sigma_y$

[reference](http://web.ist.utl.pt/susanavinga/renyi/convolution_normal.pdf)

- now my question: are you aware of any operator (such as $+$, $*$, etc) applicable on Gaussian PDFs such that the outcome parameters look something like this? $\mu_z = \mu_x + \mu_y$ and $\Sigma_z= \sqrt{\Sigma_x^2 + \Sigma_y^2}$

in the other words, I want to know what can happen between PDFs of $X$ and $Y$ such that the out-coming PDF has parameters like I mentioned above ([Pythagorean sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_addition) is called?).

Comment: The "sum" operation can't be any old sum (for $h(Z)$ to be a normalized density):  it must be a convex combination, giving a gaussian mixture.  And in that case $\mu_z  \neq \mu_x + \mu_y$, but will be that same convex combination of $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$.  Perhaps you can provide some motivation for this question, because there might be another way to solve your problem.

Comment: @AndrewM The sum is just an example for what I want to ask. You can only consider the second example about convolution, if it is more clear. In my problem, I deal with real-value Multivariate Gaussians, if it helps. Does it make sense?